# Image masking algorithms

Tags: image, encryption, image-processing, masking

I am working on an image encryption and decryption project with 3 levels of security.
The latter levels of security involve false image addition and cryptographical enhancement.
I am looking for encryption on the first level of security.
Can you suggest an algorithm in which I can mask the image on the encryption side and the same image has to be got back(after removing the mask) on the decryption side.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be more precise about what you have and what you want. masking and decryption is very large. I think what you search for is steganography

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography